# handle multiple domains with Access-Control-Allow-Origin header in Apache

Tags: apache, .htaccess, http, cross-domain, cors

I want to configure apache for cross-domain access header. I have tried multiple combination as suggested on number of threads on the forum. But its not working for me.

The ways, I have tried:

1) Specify domain on different line as below with `Header set` :

```
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "example1.com"
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "example2.com"
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin: "example3.com"
```

With this setup its picking **only last one** and ignore rest of all.

2) Specify domain on different line as below with `Header add` :

```
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "example1.com"
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "example2.com"
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin: "example3.com"
```

With this its showing all three domains in header, but fonts are not getting picked up on Firefox.

3.) Tried Using `SetEnvIf`, but again its not working :

```
SetEnvIf Origin "http(s)?://(www\.)?(mydomain.com|mydomain2.com)$" AccessControlAllowOrigin=$0$1
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin %{AccessControlAllowOrigin}e env=AccessControlAllowOrigin
```

Finally working with "*", but I don't want to use this.

Please help with this.

Comment: Did you read this one : http://stackoverflow.com/a/4730826/550618 for problems with 304 response code?

Comment: If I use "Header set", then its working on FF. But in that case Its taking only last domain :( and I want to configure for multiple domains.

Comment: the problem is not `set` or `add`, it's to add the `always` keyword

Comment: Still having the same issue. If I use "always" keyword with set as below :
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "example1.com"
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "example2.com"
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin: "example3.com"

Then its taking only last domain and fonts work on FF. On the other hand if I use always keyword with add as below :

Header always add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "example1.com"
Header always add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "example2.com"
Header always add Access-Control-Allow-Origin: "example3.com"

Then fonts doesn't work on FF.

Comment: hi experts-
Can you please guide me on this?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Web Applications Stack Exchange](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/), [Webmaster Stack Exchange](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 56):

For 3 domains, in your .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    SetEnvIf Origin "http(s)?://(www\.)?(domain1.org|domain2.com|domain3.net)$" AccessControlAllowOrigin=$0$1
    Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin %{AccessControlAllowOrigin}e env=AccessControlAllowOrigin
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Credentials true
</IfModule>
```

I've tried this and it works for me. Let me know if it doesn't for you.

Comment: This is the only way, it dynamically serve only one value by checking the host before serving. The "always append" or "add" didn't work for me.

Comment: Works great for me. I am wondering about "$0$1", as many other example just use "$0". It looks like it's robustness when re-using same .htaccess file for different web servers ($0 works for Apache).

Comment: Since the Response might differ depending on the "Origin" field, maybe the `Vary: Origin` header should be set as well (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25329405/why-isnt-vary-origin-response-set-on-a-cors-miss)

Comment: It only worked for me when leaving the "$1" away. For some reason "$1" was set to "s" and therefore it did not match ("domain1.org" did not match "domain1.orgs").

Comment: This is wrong. It needs to be `$0`, not `$0$1`. `$0$1` will append the matching group 1 to the URL. This is the matching group 1: `http(s)?` So it will append `s` for https origins and `undefined` for http origins.

Comment: Agreed, using $0 is preferred. But the answer is freaking-awesome! Thanks, George!

Comment: On second thought, it might be beneficial to drop unwanted parts of the request Origin. One could use `(http(s)?://(myapp(api)?\-(dev|demo)\.azurewebsites\.net|localhost|localhost:4444)).*$`, which will accept multiple hosts/urls but place only the protocol and server in `$1`.

Comment: Can anyone explain to me what the 'e' means in the expression `%{AccessControlAllowOrigin}e` ?

Comment: Working great in 2020, just had to remove $1 to make it work, thanks for this solution

Comment: @FabienHaddadi %{AccessControlAllowOrigin}e is a type of format specifier for the header directive. https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_headers.html#header

Answer (score 18):

Unless I'm misunderstanding [the manual](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_headers.html#header), it should be:

```
Header always append Access-Control-Allow-Origin: "example1.com"
Header always append Access-Control-Allow-Origin: "example2.com"
Header always append Access-Control-Allow-Origin: "example3.com"
```

The manual states that the `set` and `add` actions behave in the following way:

**set:** "The response header is set, replacing any previous header with this name"

**add:** "...This can result in two (or more) headers having the same name. This can lead to unforeseen consequences..."

Comment: the manual also says `append... This is the HTTP standard way of giving a header multiple values.`

Comment: My god thank you. Took me a lot of fumbling around to find this.

Comment: You cant have multiple headers https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS/Errors/CORSMultipleAllowOriginNotAllowed

Comment: Doesn't work ...

Answer (score 4):

To restrict access to certain URIs checkout these docs:

[CrossOriginRequestSecurity](https://code.google.com/p/html5security/wiki/CrossOriginRequestSecurity)

[Server-Side Access Control#Apache_examples](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Server-Side_Access_Control#Apache_examples)

One helpful trick is to use an Apache rewrite, environment variable, and headers to apply Access-Control-Allow-* to certain URIs. This is useful, for example, to constrain cross-origin requests to GET /api(.*).json requests without credentials:

```
RewriteRule ^/api(.*)\.json$ /api$1.json [CORS=True]
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*" env=CORS
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "GET" env=CORS
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Credentials "false" env=CORS
```

Also, in general, according to [W3 Wiki - CORS Enabled#For_Apache](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CORS_Enabled#For_Apache)
To expose the header, you can add the following line inside Directory, Location, and Files sections, or within an .htaccess file.

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
  Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
</IfModule>
```

AND, you can use add rather than set, but be aware that add can add the header multiple times, so it's generally safer to use set.

Answer (score 4):

Try this one, it works for me. 
Apply in .htaccess:

```
SetEnvIf Origin "^http(s)?://(.+\.)?(domain\.org|domain2\.com)$" origin_is=$0 
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin %{origin_is}e env=origin_is
```

Answer (score 1):

> Will be work 100%, Apply in .htaccess:

```
# Enable cross domain access control
SetEnvIf Origin "^http(s)?://(.+\.)?(domain1\.com|domain2\.org|domain3\.net)$" REQUEST_ORIGIN=$0
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin %{REQUEST_ORIGIN}e env=REQUEST_ORIGIN
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS"
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "x-test-header, Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept"

# Force to request 200 for options
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} OPTIONS
RewriteRule .* / [R=200,L]
```

Comment: Both this and the approved answer adds a * at the end which isn't correct. I.E If I make a request from localhost:3000 the response header contains:
`Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:3000, *`

Answer (score 0):

For Apache 2.4, I have used SET command for the Apache web server to set Header dynamically.

```
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
  # CORS
  SetEnvIfNoCase Origin "http(s)?://(\w+\.)?(example.com|localhost)(:[0-9]+)?$" AccessControlAllowOrigin=$0
  Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin %{AccessControlAllowOrigin}e env=AccessControlAllowOrigin
  Header set Access-Control-Allow-Credentials true
</IfModule>
```

ADD command didn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

I am using this in my `.htaccess` file for **allowing access to multiple domains**

```
 <ifModule mod_headers.c>
    SetEnvIf Origin "http(s)?://(localhost:25120|domain.com|domain2.com)$" AccessControlAllowOrigin=$0
    Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin %{AccessControlAllowOrigin}e env=AccessControlAllowOrigin
    Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Methods: "GET,POST,OPTIONS,DELETE,PUT"
 </ifModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

For Multiple domains, in your .htaccess:

```
 <IfModule mod_headers.c>
    SetEnvIf Origin "http(s)?://(www\.)?(domain.com|domain.online|domain.in|domain.net|domain.site|domain.website|domain.space)$" AccessControlAllowOrigin=$0
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin %{AccessControlAllowOrigin}e env=AccessControlAllowOrigin
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Credentials true
</IfModule>
```

it 100% works for me

Answer (score -2):

This works for me in Classic ASP:

```
If Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_ORIGIN") = "http://domain1.com" Then
  Response.AddHeader "Access-Control-Allow-Origin","http://domain1.com"
ElseIf Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_ORIGIN") = "http://domain2.com" Then
  Response.AddHeader "Access-Control-Allow-Origin","http://domain2.com"
'and so on
End If
```

Comment: The question is about Apache.