# Access-Control-Allow-Origin doesn't work if wrapped inside FilesMatch

Tags: regex, cors, access-control

```
    <FilesMatch "\.(json|txt)$" >
       SetEnvIf Origin "http(s)?://(www\.)?(sub.domain.com|sub2.domain.com|www.domain2.com)$" AccessControlAllowOrigin=$0$1
       Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin %{AccessControlAllowOrigin}e env=AccessControlAllowOrigin
       Header set Access-Control-Allow-Credentials true
       Header set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept"
    </FilesMatch>
```

If I use middle block on it's own (without FilesMatch) then it works and i can make my request. If I test my FilesMatch by putting *Deny from all* inside it then it clearly works as well. But put both of them together and I can't make the request. It seems to go thrum, but without credentials and throws out *Access-Control-Allow-Origin* warning.

Comment: refer this post with success message with your same code http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20673882/handle-multiple-domains-with-access-control-allow-origin-header-in-apache/22331450#22331450

Comment: @ZigmaEmpire I don't have problem with setting Access-Control-Allow-Origin, i can't do it together with FilesMatch, it just doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to put your **\.** inside the brackets

```
<FilesMatch "(?<!\.json|\.txt)$">
```

Try to enclose your expression as string, like **"%{AccessControlAllowOrigin}e"**

```
<FilesMatch "(?<!\.json|\.txt)$" >
       SetEnvIf Origin "http(s)?://(www\.)?(sub.domain.com|sub2.domain.com|www.domain2.com)$" AccessControlAllowOrigin=$0$1
       Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "%{AccessControlAllowOrigin}e" env=AccessControlAllowOrigin
       Header set Access-Control-Allow-Credentials true
       Header set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept"
</FilesMatch>
```

Comment: Sadly didn't help. As soon as I add "<FilesMatch "\.(json|txt)$" >" it stops working.

Comment: Edit my answer, can you check the new expression (?<!\.json|\.txt)$

Comment: try changing **FilesMatch** to **filesMatch**