# bootstrap glyphicons in cross domain doesn't works

Tags: css, iis, twitter-bootstrap-3, cross-domain, glyphicons

I have a base site with all my code javascript and dependencies to jquery and bootstrap, so I don't need each time to copy all this files to a new site. For example, my base site is on localhost/basesite, so new sites uses bootstrap like that:

```
<link href="http://localhost/basesite/content/bootstrap/css/boostrap.css rel='stylesheet' />
```

and for scripts:

```
<script src='http://localhost/basesite/scripts/bootstrap.js'></script>
```

Evereything works fine, but bootstrap glyphicons doesn't, 'cause 3 files in fonts directory are not correctly loaded:

```
../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.[woff, ttf, svg]
```

These files are in fonts directory of bootstrap, and the browser can get correctly just the file **glyphicons-halflings-regular.eof**, witch is in the same directory.

If I open my base site, glyphicon works like a charm, so there is no problem with fonts directory location.

I think this is a problem of cross domain, but my site is already configured to use that.

In Chrome, I got 304 and 206. I really can't understand that. Here a printscreen from Google Chrome:

[image: Network tab from google chrome]

[image: Details from 206]

[image: Details from 304]

Best Regards

Answer (score 0):

It seems the problem is with font folder permissions, and probably the font request are returning a 403 error (Forbidden) and causing the problem, adjusting the permissions and tray again, check network panel on google chrome or firebug to get more info about the problem, if the problem is url path network panel show you this error, tray put full path in url font like: http://www.yourdomain.com/folderpath/fontname...

Comment: I already did put full path, but the errors remains. And the returned code error is 404, because it tries to get these files at the bad location.

Comment: Can you put a image of your google chrome network panel?

Comment: I can't understand, in Chrome I got 304 and 206.

Comment: can you click on one of the errors and put the image of headers panel

Comment: Yes, of course... it is not an error, I got 304 and 206, but the glyphicons doesn't works.

Comment: check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23888889/can-i-set-an-access-control-allow-origin-header-to-all-pages-on-a-domain-and-its